# Database backup and restore incase Always Encrypted feature is enabled

Tags: sql-server, backup, encryption, always-encrypted

I would like to know that How SQL database backup and its restoration on other server will work if Always Encrypted feature is implemented on most of its tables?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Sunny What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with "Window Certificate Store - Current User" and "Windows Certificate Store - Local machine (localhost) and concluded to.

Existence of any object related to Always Encrypted features (master key, column master key and the certificates used to create the master key) is limited to the database only.

So simple backup and restore process works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thanks for the response! Is there anything extra need to perform on Always Encrypted database if i am restoring a .bak file to another server or will it normally work without doing anything in addition? Thanks!

Comment: Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) and Always Encrypted (AE) are 2 different features of SQL Server. TDE helps you in entire database security whereas AE helps you to secure sensitive data with a database. If you use TDE then yes you need to restore/create master key and certificates on target server before DB restore but not in case of AE.